# Image assets and NSImageView

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nsimageview, xcasset

I have a macOS project, and I want to display a static image.
I'm always annoyed with image assets and Image View.
First, I imported an image in image assets, but I couldn't select the name in the NSImageView in IB. So, I typed directly the name, but I didn't see the image in IB. I build and run, it doesn't appear on the finished app too.

I tried several options (some of them found here): quit / relaunch XCode, clean project, delete / reimport the image with no luck.

If I import the file of the image in the project, in addition with the image asset, now I can see the image in Interface Builder, is it how it is supposed to work? The image must be referenced two times in XCode?

After that, my image isn't showing in the compiled app, even if it has been copied in the bundle, there's nothing in the window except the text, and there is no error in debugger.

I should have missed something obvious?

Comment: same question here. apple.. so tenacious to build